# Laravel 5.0-5.2: How a custom request class return a json error mesage?

Tags: php, laravel

I download a starter project which is written in laravel 5.0, it has a class:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests\Admin;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class VendorRequest extends  FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|integer',
        ];
    }
}
```

In controller use the above class

```
public function postEdit(VendorRequest $request, $id)
{

}
```

If the form does not meet the rules, it will return a json with error messages `"{name: ["The name must be an integer."]}"` (**the main problem is that didn't see any code will return a json**), a javascript in `resources\views\layouts\modal.blade.php` will popup the error message, the code is as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head id="Starter-Site">

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<title>Administration</title>

<meta name="keywords" content="@yield('keywords')" />
<meta name="author" content="@yield('author')" />
<!-- Google will often use this as its description of your page/site. Make it good. -->
<meta name="description" content="@yield('description')" />
<!-- Speaking of Google, don't forget to set your site up: http://google.com/webmasters -->
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="">
<!-- Dublin Core Metadata : http://dublincore.org/ -->
<meta name="DC.title" content="Project Name">
<meta name="DC.subject" content="@yield('description')">
<meta name="DC.creator" content="@yield('author')">
<!--  Mobile Viewport Fix -->
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/colorbox.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet) }}}" type="text/css">
<link href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/jquery.multiselect.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/style_modal.min.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/css/select2.css') }}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/summernote.css')}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/summernote-bs3.css')}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link
    href="{{asset('assets/admin/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- The HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
<!-- start: Favicon and Touch Icons -->
<link rel="shortcut icon"
    href="{{{ asset('assets/admin/ico/favicon.ico') }}}">
<!-- end: Favicon and Touch Icons -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Container -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header"></div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm close_popup">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span> {{{
                Lang::get('admin/admin.back') }}}
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Content -->
        @yield('content')
        <!-- ./ content -->
    </div>
    <!-- ./ container -->
    <!-- start: JavaScript-->
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <script src="{{{ asset('assets/admin/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js') }}}"></script>
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE]>
        <script src="{{{ asset('assets/admin/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js') }}}"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    <script src="{{{ asset('assets/admin/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}}"></script>
    <!-- page scripts -->
    <script src="{{{ asset('assets/admin/js/jquery-ui.1.11.2.min.js') }}}"></script>
    <script src="{{{ asset('assets/admin/js/jquery.colorbox.js') }}}"></script>
    <script src="{{  asset('assets/admin/js/summernote.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{  asset('assets/admin/js/select2.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('textarea').summernote({height: 250});
                $('form').submit(function(event) {

                    event.preventDefault();
                    var form = $(this);

                    if (form.attr('id') == '' || form.attr('id') != 'fupload'){
                        $.ajax({
                              type : form.attr('method'),
                              url : form.attr('action'),
                              data : form.serialize()
                              }).success(function() {
                                  setTimeout(function() {
                                      parent.$.colorbox.close();
                                      window.parent.location.reload();
                                      }, 10);
                            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                                var textResponse = jqXHR.responseText;
                                var alertText = "One of the following conditions is not met:\n\n";
                                var jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(textResponse);

                                $.each(jsonResponse, function(n, elem) {
                                    alertText = alertText + elem + "\n";
                                });
                                alert(alertText);
                            });
                        }
                    else{
                        var formData = new FormData(this);
                        $.ajax({
                              type : form.attr('method'),
                              url : form.attr('action'),
                              data : formData,
                              mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
                              contentType: false,
                              cache: false,
                              processData:false
                        }).success(function() {
                              setTimeout(function() {
                                  parent.$.colorbox.close();
                                  window.parent.location.reload();
                                  }, 10);

                        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            // Optionally alert the user of an error here...
                            var textResponse = jqXHR.responseText;
                            var alertText = "One of the following conditions is not met:\n\n";
                            var jsonResponse = jQuery.parseJSON(textResponse);

                            $.each(jsonResponse, function(n, elem) {
                                alertText = alertText + elem + "\n";
                            });

                            alert(alertText);
                        });
                    };
                });

                $('.close_popup').click(function() {
                    parent.$.colorbox.close()
                    window.parent.location.reload();
                });
            });
        </script>
    @yield('scripts')
</body>
</html>
```

The questions are:

1. how the request class return the error message in json?
2. if I don't want to use request class for validation, how can I do the same thing in controller? 
   I had tried return the json but it didn't popup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Validate` class in controller:

```
    $validate = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**About 2nd**

In your controller remove Request DI and validate params by [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation):

```
public function postEdit($id)
{
    $validate = Validator::make(Request::all(), [
       'name' => 'required|integer'
    ]);

    /** If params not valid return your json */ 
    if ($validate->fails()) {
        // return json
    }
}
```